# fatal error uncaught error call to a member function get_price() on null

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

please help me….
When I import, WooCommerce product, showing the following errors.

fatal error uncaught error call to a member function get_price() on null in home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/inc/wc-products-functions.php 1046.
I have added these codes in the fucntions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_price_display' );
function sv_change_product_price_display( $price, $product  ) {
  global $product;
  if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) return $price;
  $price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ); 
  $price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ); 
  $price = '<p class="price">' . __("Ex. VAT:") . wc_price( $price_excl_tax ) . '</p>';
  $price .= '<p class="price-incl">' . __("Incl. VAT:") . wc_price( $price_incl_tax ) . '</p>';

   return $price;
 }
```

please note: I am using the Currency Switcher for WooCommerce plugin.

please check the following attached file:

[image]

Someone, please help me

Thanks

Comment: The error occurs in the `wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product )` function. Check `$product`, it seems to be `null`, but then should there an error in the line above. Confusing...

Comment: thanks and I am new here, so can you show me please any an example. thanks for your time